# Python: If dataframe has a column name containing a certain string, append column to different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, columnsorting

I've seen this answered a lot for values, but not for the column header itself.

Say I have my original dataframe, `df1`:

```
   axx  byy  czz
0    1    2    3
1    4    5    6
```

And a second dataframe, `df2`:

```
   dd  ee
0   7   8
1   9  10
```

If dataframe 1 contains the string sequence "yy" , append the whole column (values included) to dataframe 2, so in the end for `df2` I would get this:

```
   dd  ee  byy
0   7   8    2
1   9  10    5
```

How do I do this? I know it has something along the lines of `df1.columns.str.contains('yy')` but this returns a boolean, and I can't work out how to use that to copy over and append the entire column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` for this:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df2, df1.filter(like='yy')], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
   dd  ee  byy
0   7   8    2
1   9  10    5
```

Or `df.columns.str.contains`, like you were thinking:

```
yy_cols = df1.columns[df1.columns.str.contains('yy')]
new_df = pd.concat([df2, df1[yy_cols]], axis=1)
```